# Passing a column name to a ggplot function with aes

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

You have a plot function that you want to pass a column name to, as seen below:

```
plottr <- function(df, flag, flagaes) {
    ddply(df, flag, summarize, pct = sum(hitbox==1)/length(hitbox)) %>%
    ggplot(aes_string(x=flagaes, y='pct')) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
}
```

The issue that many people (including me) face is that the ddply function takes the column name as is and finds it in your dataframe. Aes however doesn't know how to handle a string. How do we solve this?

Comment: How are you trying to call this function? What types of objects are you passing to each of the parameters?

Comment: I pasted your question title into SO search panel and immediately got that duplicate. I suspect there are many other duplicates as well that would show up if we used a slight modication. If you are going to post question/answer combinations that you already have, you should do a good faith search to see if you can find one or more. If your question is somewhat different in important ways, you should reference the ones that are close and explain why they are not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

First, for the `flag` variable, pass the column name with the `as.name` function to remove it from string form. The reason for this is if you do not pass as a string, R will attempt to find a variable with the name you've entered.

Next, `aes` needs to be called as `aes_string` to pass the column name to it, but then tries to stringr the `pct`. As seen above, this can be remedied by backticking the column name in the ggplot function, seen as `` \`pct`\ `` in the function above.

I thought it would be good to share this for future users and I'm sure this isn't the cleanest way to accomplish this.